# VirtualHost - point all domains to root folder and one domain to a subfolder in the root folder

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost

I have tried but nothing seems to work for me here. I have an Apache server with multiple domains set up. Currently they all point to the root folder (C:\xampp\htdocs) but I'd like to organize things a little better here on. I'd like to use Apache's VirtualHost to point each new domain to a subfolder inside this folder but have all older websites point to C:\xampp\htdocs in the mean time until I can migrate each.

The issue is that when I use the following code, all my domains point to the subfolder

```
# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\newdomain\"
    ServerName www.newdomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I need to add a Virtual that listens to all other domains and points them to C:\xampp\htdocs
But I'm running out of ideas. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that:

```
# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName _default_
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\newdomain"
    ServerName www.newdomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

You need a **default virtualhost**, that's the catch_all thing, when the Host Header defined in the HTTP query does not match any `ServerName` directive the default VH is useD. And the default VH is the **first one defined** in the configuration.